# Why is lambda asking for 2 arguments despite being given 2 arguments?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, lambda

This is my code:

`filter(lambda n,r: not n%r,range(10,20))`

I get the error:

`TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

So then I tried:

`foo=lambda n,r:not n%r`

Which worked fine. So I thought this will work:

`bar=filter(foo,range(10,20))`

but again:

`TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Something similar happens for map as well. But reduce works fine. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something crucial needed in order to use filter or map?

Comment: `filter()` passes a single argument to your lambda, when it expects two. Using a variable won't let you get around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you use 2 arguments? `filter()` and `map()` require a function with a single argument only, e.g.:

```
filter(lambda x: x >= 2, [1, 2, 3])
>>> [2, 3]
```

To find the factors of a number (you can substitute it with lambda as well):

```
def factors(x):
    return [n for n in range(1, x + 1) if x % n == 0]

factors(20)
>>> [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So then how do I go about writing this code, which has to return factors for a number. I want to use filter or map so that I understand it better...or at least lambda

Comment: Of course you could optimize this to just search up to sqrt(x), and add x/n and n to the results whenever `x % n == 0`. It will make a difference when the numbers get larger.

Answer (score 5):

If you run map or filter on a key-value set, then 
add parentheses around (k,v), like:

```
  .filter(lambda (k,v): k*2 + v)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `filter` in python takes only one argument. So you need to define a lambda/function that takes only one argument if you want to use it in filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function takes two arguments `n` and `r`.  `filter` must be called with a function that takes one argument and returns `True` when the item should be kept.  Maybe you meant to define `r` or `n` outside your lambda function and then capture it in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of nature of implementation of map function, the second argument to map, reduce and filter is list but how it reads and passes values to the first argument of these methods differ, if you see below reduce function default picks 2 elements from list and passes to lambda however filter and map expects only one element.

```
>>>reduce(lambda x,y: x+ y,range(10))  
45  

>>>filter(lambda x,y: x+ y,range(10))  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)  
>>>filter(lambda x: x+ 1,range(10))  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
>>>  

>>>map(lambda x,y: x+ y,range(10))    
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)  
>>>  
>>>map(lambda x: x+1, range(10))  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  
>>>
```

Comment: Your original problem can be solved using list comprehension as below        >>> [n for n in range(10,20) for r in range(10,20) if not n%r]  
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]  
>>>